# Growth estimate of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have not even understood the statement clearly to attempt it !

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function and that there exist two real numbers $M > 0$ and $p ≥ 1$ such
that $|f (z)| ≤ M (1 + |z|^p )\quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. Describe, giving a rigorous argument, all the entire functions that satisfy this growth estimate.

I know what an entire function is and Power series development of homomorphic functions. BUt I am unable to understand this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the special case of p = 0?

Comment: Yes I guess. That will be lieuveil theorem  right ?

Comment: Indeed, so what you need to do is to generalize Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks but can you help me with answer so that I can figure out ? Maybe hints/ steps to complete the answer.

Comment: Start with writing down the contour integral expression for the coefficient of $z^n$ for a general holomorphic function.

Comment: @CountIblis : can you precise what was your idea ?

Comment: @user1952009 You can write: $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(R)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$ where C(R) is a counterclockwise circle of radius R and the origin as its center. Then if you consider the modulus of $c_n$ use that the modulus of the integral is equal or less than the integral of the modulus of the integrand, you find an upper bound for $|c_n|$ that tends to zero for R to infinity when n is larger than p, therefore all these coefficients are zero and the function is a polynomial of degree m such than $m\leq p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace $p$ by $\lceil p \rceil$ so now $p \in \mathbb{N}$. let $$f_0(z) = f(z), \qquad \qquad \qquad f_{n+1}(z) = \frac{f_n(z)-f_n(0)}{z}$$

hence at least when $|z| \to \infty$ : $f_n(z) \le (M+\epsilon)(1+|z|^{p-n})$ and we can apply the [Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) to $f_p(z)$ which is a bounded entire function. thus $f_p(z) = C$ and

$$f_{n}(z) = z f_{n+1}(z)+f_{n}(0) \quad \text{is a degree $p-n$ polynomial }$$
 $\implies f(z) = f_0(z)$ is a degree $p$ polynomial.

(of course if at first $p$ wasn't an integer the coefficient of $z^{\lceil p \rceil}$ has to be $0$ and $f(z)$ is a degree $\lfloor p \rfloor$ polynomial)